# Laravel code optimization : count number of tasks in a particular project in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, collections, count, statistics

How can I optimize my Laravel code? Such as counting the number of tasks in a particular project according to a task's status (done, todo, doing).

```
public function ShowTaskStatus(Project $project)
{
    $tasks = $project->tasks()->get();
    $totaltask = $tasks->count();
    $totaltask_doing = $tasks->where('status', "TODo")->groupBy('status')
        ->map(function ($row) {

            return $row->count();
        });
    $totaltask_todo = $tasks->where('status', "Doing")->groupBy('status')
        ->map(function ($row) {

            return $row->count();
        });
    $totaltask_done = $tasks->where('status', "Done")->groupBy('status')
        ->map(function ($row) {

            return $row->count();
        });

    return [$totaltask, $totaltask_doing, $totaltask_todo, $totaltask_done];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the counts from different type of task, then dont retrieve them with `get()`

Use the queryBuilder `count()` method instead of the collection `count()` method

```
public function ShowTaskStatus(Project $project)
{
    $taskCount = $project->tasks()->count();
    $taskToDoCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "TODo")->count();
    $taskDoingCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "Doing")->count();
    $taskDoneCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "Done")->count();
    return [$taskCount,$taskToDoCount, $taskDoingCount, $taskDoneCount];
}
```

If you only have those statuses, you can also omit the `$taksCount` variable.

```
public function ShowTaskStatus(Project $project)
{
    $taskToDoCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "TODo")->count();
    $taskDoingCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "Doing")->count();
    $taskDoneCount = $project->tasks()->where('status', "Done")->count();
    return [$taskToDoCount + $taskDoingCount + $taskDoneCount, $taskToDoCount, $taskDoingCount, $taskDoneCount];
}
```

You will notice a big difference in performance from doing a get then counting and doing the counting directly in the DB. especially if you have a lot of tasks entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query;

```
return $project->tasks()->toBase()
       ->selectRaw(count(*) as total)
       ->selectRaw(count(case when status='TODo'  then 1 end) as todo)
       ->selectRaw(count(case when status='Doing' then 1 end) as doing)
       ->selectRaw(count(case when status='Done'  then 1 end) as done)
       ->first()
       ->values();
```